# Consulta SQL con arreglo de datos

Tags: php, html, session

ACTUALIZO: estoy trabajando en un proyecto el cual consta de una pagina de venta de productos, con carrito incluido, a medida de que voy agregando productos a la variable de SESSION del carrito necesito que los mismos que ya están agregados ya no se muestren en mi pagina de inicio, ya no estén disponibles para la vista del usuario, ya que ya lo tiene agregado a su carrito, adjunto lo que hay guardado en la variable de SESSION carrito (ACLARO QUE LA CREACION DE LA VARIABLE DE SESSION CARRITO OCURRE EN OTRA PAGINA DISTINTA A LA DE ABAJO):

```
$arreglo[] = array(
          'Id'=> $_GET['id'],
          'Nombre'=> $nombre,
          'Precio'=> $precio,
          'Categoria'=> $categoria,
          'Imagen'=> $imagen,
          'Cantidad'=> 1
      );
      $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
```

Luego tengo una variable en la cual dentro tengo los datos de la variable de session vista mas arriba. Mediante una consulta SQL necesito dejar afuera a todos los productos los cuales ya se encuentren dentro de la variable de session, yo tenia pensado algo así, pero pensándolo bien, solo te oculta el ultimo objeto agregado al arreglo, no se me ocurre una forma de hacerlo, alguna ayuda?

```
$arreglo =$_SESSION['carrito'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo);$i++) { 
   $resultado = $conexion ->query("select * from productos where id!=".$arreglo[$i]['Id']." and inventario>0 limit ".$limite)or die($conexion->error);
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu a tu pregunta le falta algo de cuerpo y explicación de que intentas hacer, ya que no logro entender. Por favor agrega un buen ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr, explicando si es posible con ese `Array` de ejemplo

Comment: Favor de agregar aquí el contenido de `$_SESSION['carrito']`, hazle un echo.

Comment: no uses igual.. lee sobre la clausula IN en sql

Comment: Actualice con un poco mas de información sobre lo que trata mi proyecto para ver si puedes darte una idea de lo que quiero hacer.@Josbert

Comment: @gbianchi Cambie mi consulta por esta: ```$resultado = $conexion ->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id NOT IN (".$arreglo[$i]['Id'].") and inventario>0 limit ".$limite)or die($conexion->error);``` pero aun asi no logro que funcione, ya que yo necesito dejar afuera a TODOS los objetos que esten en la base de datos y correspondan con algun id que ya exista en mi variable de session carrito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero almacena los ids de los productos de la session en otro arreglo.

```
$ids = array();

foreach ($arreglo as $item) {
    $ids[] = $item['Id'];
}
```

Luego conviertes ese nuevo array de ids a string separados por coma con la funcion **implode**.

```
$ids = implode(",", $ids);// ejm $ids = "1,2,3,4";
```

Luego en el string de SQL utiliza **NOT IN** y en los parentesis pasale la variable **$ids** que contiene este string por ejemplo **1,2,3,4**

```
$resultado = $conexion ->query("select * from productos where id NOT IN($ids) and inventario>0 limit ".$limite)or die($conexion->error);
```

Ya no haria falta el bucle **for**

Comment: De 10! era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!